# Using SQL LIKE with another query

Tags: sql, sql-like

I have this sql query for searching:

```
select * 
from songs 
where name LIKE '%search%' 
   or author LIKE '%search%' 
   or tags LIKE '%search%';
```

At this point everything is OK, but now I need to search only in the songs where the column '*status*' = 1. How can I do this?

Comment: not a great "research effort"...

Comment: I would like to improve it. Any suggestion?

Comment: yes, next time try using google before asking. eg. search for "sql multiple search criteria". also remember to accept the right answer

Comment: I did use google before asking. And as you can see there are two right (and same) answers posted at almost same time. By the way, those 2 things are no suggestion to improve the query.

Comment: Consider them suggestions to improve your poor search skills then. By the way, consider reading http://stackoverflow.com/tour and learn about "accepting answers", you seem a bit confused.

Answer (score 2):

Add it to the where clause and put the ors in braces:

```
select * from songs where status = 1 and ( name LIKE '%search%' or author LIKE '%search%' or tags LIKE '%search%');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use parentheses to combine conditions and have an 'and' at the end so that either of the current conditions are true, and the condition you are about to add:

```
select *
from songs
where 
  (name LIKE '%search%' or
   author LIKE '%search%' or
   tags LIKE '%search%'
  ) and
  status=1;
```

Comment: why add same answer ?... .

Comment: @JuanRuizdeCastilla Mark PM and I answered within 4 seconds of each other. That is soo little time that not even the "another answer has been posted" bar showed up. I didn't delete my answer, because I believe it does have slightly more information than Mark PM's answer.